# sparkcontext from worker serialization error

Tags: apache-spark

we are unable to access sparkcontext from map transformations. Is it possible to access sparkcontext from worker nodes? We get serialization exceptions - any workaround with custom serialization? Kindly help.

Comment: What are you trying to do with SparkContext from worker node?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Spark Context can be accessed only from the driver program. There is no workaround.

Comment: I do not see I am able to access a tempview either.